# How to does indexing work in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, parameter-passing, x86-16

I'm having problems with my indexing in assembly 8086, I have a procedure in assembly that I call from C and the procedure takes an array of pointers of type `long int` defined like this `long int *arr_ptr[3]`, code is like this (I consider my `SI` to be my row pointer and `DI` to be my column pointer):

```
MOV SI,[BP+6]   ;now si points to the first row
MOV DI,[SI]     ;now DI is pointing to the first row
                ; and at the first column column 
ADD SI,2        ;here i can move the SI pointer to the next row,
                ; but i want to do this in a loop so i thought
                ; ill define a variable cnt in my data and do this
MOV DI,[SI+cnt]
```

That last line when `cnt` is 2 is not the same as `ADD SI,2` what can I do? I just want to simply loop through my matrix.

Comment: Does your C produce 16-bit code? What is the point of `long int *arr_ptr[3]`? Is that 32-bit?

Comment: Sorry but how can I find that out ?

Comment: I'm working with the .SMALL model if that's what you meant

Comment: So you are using a 20th century compiler?

Comment: Using the tcc and dosbox

Comment: Do you mean Turbo C?

Comment: Yes im using the Turbo C,and never mind what i'm trying to do i'm just trying to understand how to comfortably loop through a matrix in assembly

Comment: matrices are usually defined as `element_type matrix[M*N];` (or `... matrix[N][M];` which is the same thing), the second indirection of the pointers-per-row has quite some performance hit and for common cases like 3D matrices (i.e. 4x4 and similar size) the ordinary array is much better. In special case of uncommon size and some dynamic reallocation it may be better to use second layer of indirection, but that's very rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must pass down the count of rows (assuming that's variable), or terminate the row pointers with a `NULL` ptr (my preference).  Or build a struct containing all the needed info -- row count, data addr -- and pass its ptr to your processing routine.

Assuming you've `NULL` terminated the row ptrs, the assembly code might look like this:

```
    mov   si,[bp+6]
    jmp short rowloopentry
rowloop:
    << process row data pointed to by di >>
rowloopentry:
    mov   di,[si]                   ;get next row data ptr, and advance index
    add   si,2
    test  di,di                     ;process next row if not at end
    jnz   rowloop
```

Alternatively if the row count is passed as an argument the prototype might become `func(long int *arr_ptr[], unsigned rowcnt);` and the processing code could loop as follows:

```
    mov   cx,[bp+8]
    mov   si,[bp+6]
    test  cx,cx
    jz    zerorows
rowloop:
    mov   di,[si]                   ;get next row data ptr, and advance index
    add   si,2
    << process row data pointed to by di >>
    loop  rowloop                   ;process next row if not at end
zerorows:
```

The above ignores optimizing for a particular processor architecture.